# ipython runs older version of script first before running new version

Tags: python, ipython

I edited *oldscript.py* and then saved it in the same directory as *newscript.py*. After this, when I do *%run newscript.py* in ipython it seems to run *oldscript.py* before running *newscript.py*. I know this because it gives an output from *oldscript.py* before giving the outputs for *newscript.py*. It looks something like this:

```
%run newscript.py
output from oldscript.py
outputs from newscript.py
```

Why is it doing this? I've deleted the .pyc files, but that didn't help. I restarted ipython, my terminal, and my computer and nothing has changed. As far as I know, I don't have anything pointing to *oldsript.py* in *newscript.py*. I'm in the correct directory. I also tried running it in spyder and the terminal. Both give the same outputs. I feel like I've tried everything.

Also, I should mention that I'm new to python so there may be an obvious solution I haven't tried. Please advise :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I just figured it out. I removed *oldscript.py* from the directory and it worked! Who knew Python could be so particular?! Okay, probably a lot of you, but give me a break I'm a noob ;)

Comment: This is not expected behaviour, and while your solution may have fixed the apparent problem, there may be something more at fault.

Comment: I thought it was a little odd, too. Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Perhaps if you posted both scripts I could test.